# SilverStripe: How do I insert a tab before another tab?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to insert a new admin tab before Root.Content.Main without any luck. I've tried:

```
$fields->insertBefore(new Tab('Root.Content.Overview', 'Overview'), 'Root.Content.Main');
```

and

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content', new Tab('OverviewTab', 'Root.Content.Overview'), 'Root.Content.Main');
```

without any luck.

Anyone have any ideas? I've hunted through the API but there isn't much explanation as to how the tab naming system works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
$fields->insertBefore(new Tab('Overview', 'Project Overview'), 'Main');
```